# .Net 7.0 arm64 installer broken?

Tags: .net, zsh

Today I tried installing .net to learn basics of it. However, after running the installer I was not able to run dotnet commands in my zh shell. ( Command not found )

I am sure that the install was successful due to my installer logs:

[image: Installer logs]

However, I cannot find the dotnet exe file anywhere in my file system. Not in the default usr/local/share/dotnet that it should be.

[image: Terminal serach]

Is there any other PATH that the Installer puts to dotnet files? I have no clue what I have done wrong. Just followed the recommended installer right off of Microsoft's site.

I have tried searching all my file system for an hour for the dotnet files, then searching the internet for other options for paths or what could have happened.

Expecting to find the file path and manually add it to my system path